# How can merge all Dask Data-frame partitions

Tags: python, multiprocessing, large-data, dask

I want to use Dask Dataframe and I used

```
    Sales = dd.read_csv('Sales.txt',blocksize=500000,
                     storage_options=dict(anon=True))

   Product = dd.read_csv('Product.txt')
```

for my two files and I merged two tables

```
df = sales_location = Sales.merge(Product, how='left', on ='Key')
```

The Sales files is 28M rows if I not use `blocksize` option it not makes partition and the process is being so long (even df.head()) but if I use `blocksize` (more than 1 partition) then process is sort but there is not all files, I can see only part of data.

So my question is How can make process faster and with all files. I want to create a big main file with Dask dataframe and make small data frames for analysing.